# recieved apple O Linker Error when adding ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, asihttprequest

this has made me crazy today, I use ASIHTTPRequest, http://allseeing-i.com/ , already, but here, am trying now to add it to an app, once added it gave me this crazy error.

I have started a new fresh project, and commented all related code, added the code without it, and yes, it works, added it, and it's libraries and no it doesn't work and I got this crazy Error, I'm stuck and need help.

BTW, this is the detailed error,

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.0/Symbols/usr/lib/libz.1.2.3.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.0/Symbols/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file
ld: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.0/Symbols/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Thank you,
Regards,
Ahmed

Comment: BTW, It's working on another project, but this one, i tried to delete it, and the problem exist. I don't know why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**I got the answer now.
I have copied the older version, a working version of my app. Or just create a new project and add the files that are not related to this, and make sure it's working and building.
Then, Added the frameworks from project setting (first icon on left) and then added from the build phase the correct libraries.
My problem was : I was trying to add the libraries by dragging them into my project, and the problem was specially for this one. libz.1.2.3.dylib. Thank you anyways, hope this is helpful for someone.**

Comment: I am using same ASIHTTPRequest in PhoneGap iOS Application .. steps from http://labs.grupow.com/index.php/2011/03/using-asihttprequest/ ...

I got the same error but I am not using any old project, its a new project...

Comment: Yup, I just forgot to add the library back in.